# TTS Utteranceprogresslistener does not work correctly

Tags: java, android, accessibility, text-to-speech, talkback

My app use the accessibility (TalkBack) and android TTS. I use TTS to read the TextView and use the callback methods to go to a new ViewPager page.

```
public class Player extends UtteranceProgressListener implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener{
public void onInit(int i) {}

@Override
public void onStart(String utteranceId) {...}

@Override
public void onStop(String utteranceId, boolean interrupted) {...}

@Override
public void onDone(String utteranceId) {..goNext()..}

@Override
public void onError(String utteranceId, int errorCode) {...}

@Override
public void onError(String utteranceId) {...}
}
```

Problem:

When TTS is speaking and I touch the other controls, the TalkBask kill him. The onError/onStop method should be called, but only onDone is called and I cant understand the TTS finished reading or he was killed.

I did not find callback methods in accessibility(TalkBack) and so I started using TTS but it does not work properly.

With the help of what I can read the text from TextView and understand when the reading is over?

Comment: Any luck finding a solution? I'm struggling with the same problem.